# Login using Facebook in UIwebView app

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, facebook-login, fbsdk

In my rails app user logs in Using Facebook. And it is working perfectly. 
Now am planning to have an iOS app(`UIWebView app`) for my rails app. i.e loading my website inside an WebView.

My concern is should I just have `one view controller` which loads the website or `two view controllers`, First one for native FB login using `iOS FB SDK` and other controller to load the website?

Currently I have tried with one controller and when I click on `Login using Facebook` (which is in the website) in iOS app, a Facebook login is opened in safari and after entering the credentials a blank page appears indefinitely.

Comment: i think you need to use UIApplication class and NSNotification center. and in you Webviewcontroller implement delegate methods of webview where you can compare loading URLs.

Comment: dont try to open url in safari and login instead of that open webview inside of your app otherwise  Apple will reject your app.

Comment: For new development, consider using `WKWebView` instead of `UIWebView`.

Comment: @BandishDave: How do I do that?? Every time I click on login it opens in safari.

Comment: @HalMueller: WKWebView is available in Xcode version 6.3?

Comment: Per https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/ and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/, it's available on iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite. Those came on Xcode 6.3. But...why not use Xcode 7?

Comment: @HalMueller: Thank you. Trying to update. But, It is taking too long to download and every time I loose connection it starts downloading from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could you one view controller. for login with Facebook you could refer this tutorial.[integrate login with facbook](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-facebook-login-sdk/)

Important steps

Step 1:Create Facebook app on developer app and configure your info.plist file

Step 2:Login Action Code

```
- (IBAction)signInWithFacebookClicked:(id)sender {


    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {


         // The session is open. Get the user information and update the UI.
         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                      parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name,last_name, email"}
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (!error) {
                                       // Set the use full name.

                                       NSLog(@"FBresponse: =>%@",result);
                                   }
                                   else{
                                       NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                   }
                               }];
     }];
}
```

Step 3: Handle call back

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{


    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

}



- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{


    // Handle the user leaving the app while the Facebook login dialog is being shown
    // For example: when the user presses the iOS "home" button while the login dialog is active
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];

}
```

Step 4: Then Handle FBSession block according you your requirement.
hope this will help.

Comment: Nagare: Thank you. will try. and My current app is in swift. So by any chance the resource that you mentioned above, is available in swift? That would help me understand it and modify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is iOS doesn't allow a stand alone UIWebView app. So the workaround is:

```
Have two ViewController, 
    First ViewController would be used for native FB login.
    Second ViewController would load the webapp.
```

This is how I designed the iOS UIWebview app, by having two ViewControllers.